# Triangle inequality complex analysis

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Using Triangle Inequality, prove if $|z−c| \le |c|/2$, then $|z| \ge |c|/2$.

Comment: Your caps lock key is broken. Please fix it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see there were answers already.  What is this site coming to?

Comment: @TaraB , I don't actually understand the use of triangle inequality, so wanted some answers to see if I could understand it

Comment: Did they help? $\hspace{0cm}$

Comment: a little bit, still slightly confused, I find it easier step by step unless this is as simple as it is

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to the contrary that $|z|\lt |c|/2$. Then 
$$|c|=|z+ (c-z)|\le |z|+|c-z|\lt |c|/2+|c|/2=|c|.$$
We have reached  the contradiction $|c| \lt |c|$.

**Remark:** Here is the intuition behind the calculation. Suppose that $|z|$ was  "small" ($\lt |c|/2$). We know that $|c-z|\le |c|/2$. Then we could travel from $0$ to $c$ via the detour through $z$ faster than by going directly. This violates the Triangle Inequality. So $|z|$ cannot be small, it must be $\ge |c|/2$.

Comment: where is there the use of the triangle inequality in this answer?

Comment: @jill ,  in the first inequality, of course.

Comment: At $|z+(c-z)|\le |z|+|c-z|$.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you already know that $\,|z\pm w|\ge |z|-|w|\,$ ,then

$$|c|-|z|\stackrel{\text{triangle ineq.}}\le|c-z|\stackrel{\text{given}}\le\frac{|c|}{2}\Longrightarrow|z|\ge|c|-\frac{|c|}{2}=\frac{|c|}{2}$$

Comment: I wonder whether the downvoter would explain his downvote...? So that I, and perhaps the OP, can understand better.